# hide Archive in Outlook

Tags: outlook, exchangeonline

Is is possible to hide the Online Archive in Outlook? We have archive enabled because we have in-place hold enabled, but we don't want users to use the archive features, and we don't want the Online Archive listed on the left. We are using Exchange Online, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, there's no built-in features available in either Outlook or Exchange Online admin side to achieve this.

As a workaround, you may consider replacing the users' Outlook to a version that does not support the in-place archive feature. See:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-license-requirements-for-Exchange-features-46b6b7c5-c3ca-43e5-8424-1e2807917c99

I've also tried submitting a suggestion into the dedicated feedback portal for Outlook. You can add votes or comments there as well if you'd like. Hopefully this function can be added in the future.
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/a5bc9dfd-c4bb-ed11-a81b-000d3a0450e3